# HighCharts - how to align (justify) xAxis labels left and right

Tags: highcharts, axis

I would like to align the x-axis labels and flush left to y-axis on the left and flush right on the right to y-axis in the chart shown below:

[image]

Here is the relevant code for x-axis and y-axes series:

```
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'discount_chart',
    type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
    text: "#{title_text_sense}"
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Price Range - $' },
    categories: #{price_array},
    showLastLabel: true,
  },
  yAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    type: 'linear',
    title: { text: 'Rate of Return - %' }
  },{
    min: 0,
    type: 'linear',
    title: { text: 'Disc. N.Rev./Invest.(ROI)' },
    opposite: true
  }],
```

Note that the variables are read from database so the price_array which is used to define the x-axis contains these values for this example:

["$60.00","$70.00","$80.00","$90.00","$100.00"]

Is there a way to do this in HighCharts?

Thanks.

Bharat

Comment: I am not sure if the question is clear enough, and a jsFiddle would be appreciated as well

Comment: Hello Jugal, Thanks for your response.  Here is a jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/rv46j/1/

Comment: What I am trying to do is to get $60.00 to align left where the y-axis 0 is and therefore eliminate the empty space where the chart lines begin on the left.  Similarly, the $100.00 should be where the graph cuts off instead of leaving empty space after the points where the graph terminates which is at $100.00.  Hope that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your time.  I really appreciate it.  But I figured this out.  Here is a fork of my original jsFiddle link that posted.  It does exactly what I want to do.  Basically, I removed the categories option in xAxis and then used the custom label formatter for xAxis; it did the trick for me. Below is

my Highcharts JavaScript code to do this:

```
var x_labels = ["$60.00","$70.00","$80.00","$90.00","$100.00"];
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'discount_chart',
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Big Wells 2 Economic Sensitivity Plot"
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Price Range - $'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return x_labels[this.value];
            }
        },
        showLastLabel: true,
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        type: 'linear',
        title: {
            text: 'Rate of Return - %'
        }},
    {
        min: 0,
        type: 'linear',
        title: {
            text: 'Disc. N.Rev./Invest.(ROI)'
        },
        opposite: true}],
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var seriesName = {
                'Rate of Return': 'ROR',
                'Return on Investment': 'ROI'
            }[this.series.name];
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>Price = ' + x_labels[this.x] + ', ' + seriesName + ' = ' + (Math.round(this.y * 1000) / 1000);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -20,
        y: 100,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rate of Return',
        color: 'red',
        data: [-4.608072102337354, -0.738803860865155, 4.653294970652549, 8.92228974293352, 14.025752639875485],
        pointStart: 0},
    {
        name: 'Return on Investment',
        color: 'blue',
        data: [0.5863077142857144, 0.7098245714285715, 0.8340802857142857, 0.9587922857142858, 1.083803],
        pointStart: 0,
        yAxis: 1}]
});
```

[jSFiddle Demo of above code to fork:](http://jsfiddle.net/B536E/)

Comment: Sir, I am sorry but why would you want to do it the long way by using a formatter and maintain an array of categories outside the chart options, when it can be done as easily as `pointPlacement: "on"`?

Comment: This is a BRILLIANT solution that helps the strange offset I see in my axes when I use categories vs. other types of data. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You should set the [plotOptions.line.pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.pointPlacement) property

> pointPlacement: String
>
> Possible values: null, "on", "between".
>
> In a column chart, when pointPlacement is "on", the point will not
>   create any padding of the X axis. If the pointPlacement is "between",
>   the columns will be laid out between ticks. This is useful for example
>   for visualising an amount between two points in time or in a certain
>   sector of a polar chart. Defaults to null.

Though the above API reference mentions it for column chart's its applicable to any category chart in general.
Since you don't want padding, you need to set it to `"on"`

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {            
        pointPlacement: "on"
    }
},
```

[Category Charts starting from origin @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/Jbg9L/)